# Ubuntu 16.04 logging out problem

Tags: amd-graphics, logout

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. When I want to log out, just a black screen with text appears.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Then the only way to log in again is to restart the computer. Also when I suspend, my computer doesn't want to wake up again.

Comment: Just black screen with _what_ text?

Comment: I added picture about it.